# How to make it so input can only be a number and not a string

Tags: python

I'm trying to make it so it only allows numbers, not strings.

```
number = (input("Pick a number "))
```

I have tried using `(raw_input(""))`, but this error comes up:

> "line 1, in 
>   number = (raw_input("Pick a number "))
>   NameError: name 'raw_input' is not defined"

I also tried `int(raw_input(""))`, and the same error came up.

I also tried `int(input(""))`, but an error came up aswell:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Show us your full code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response
This might be useful for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To ensure your input is a number, you can use:

```
while True:
    try:
        n = int(input("pick: "))
        break
    except:
        print("Expecting a number...")
        pass
```

Example:

```
pick: adsf
Expecting a number...
pick: dsf
Expecting a number...
pick: 2
```

The idea: casting something else than a number with `int()` throws an error, so you keep asking until no error is thrown.

If you use python2, you might prefer using `raw_input`.

Comment: That's disgusting...